# Simulation 8 bits input on Proteus

Tags: simulation, proteus, simulated

[image]I want to simulate 8-bits input for demultiplexer on Proteus. Anyone can suggest me the way to do that ?? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a series 8bit input or a DIP8 switch.[image]

This circuit does not seem correct.

You can do it with an impulse source from the Proteus sources

Comment: I need a series 8bit input sir

Comment: Oh thanks I think I understand your idea. Thanks